# Using Ray/Plane detection for collision in XNA (3D)

Tags: xna

Basically I want to use Rays and Planes in XNA (C#/.NET) to detect collisions between my models. But before I can do that I desperately need to know how they work.

Whenever I go somewhere looking for Ray/Plane examples I get nothing but picking tutorials - I'm not looking for picking tutorials...

What I've been trying to do is take a Plane, feed it 3 Vector3's so it represents a 3d primitive triangle, and fire Ray at it. The Ray is just a point in space and a direction.

My problem is that when I fire the Ray at the Plane, it gives me some results I can't make sense of. For example:

Say I have a Plane that represents a primitive with the coordinates {0,0,0}{1,0,0}{0,0,1}

Now I put a Ray at {0.5,1,0.5} (Roughly above the center of the triangular plane) and give it the direction; {0,-1,0}

This gives me 1, which is expected because the Plane is 1 units below the Ray, and the Ray is pointing down.
However when I make the Ray point at, say, {2,0,0}, it still gives me a number, which makes no sense because {2,0,0} is a point that is not on the triangle.

This is the code I've been using;

```
Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Right, Vector3.Backward);
Vector3 rayPos = new Vector3(0.5f, 1f, 0.5f);
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 1f) - rayPos;
direction.Normalize();
Ray ray = new Ray(rayPos, direction);
Console.WriteLine(ray.Intersects(plane));
```

I feel I've left out something REALLY important, and that I'm thinking about it all wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

although 2,0,0 isn't on the plane, the direction ((2,0,0) - rayPos)  is a direction that will intersect the plane (if starting from the current rayPos) and returns a result of 1.87...

Comment: Ah... See - I was under the impression that
 
    ((2,0,0) - rayPos).Normalize()

was a direction pointing at 2,0,0. How SHOULD I be getting that direction then?

Comment: to cause the ray to go in the direction of 2,0,0 it is  simply `(2,0,0).Normalize()`; which is (1,0,0).  `Ray ray = new Ray(rayPos, Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(2,0,0));`

Comment: Hey Steve. All I really want to know now is how to get a valid direction Vector. Is it just (TargetPosition - RayPosition.Normalize?

Comment: Ah - I think I know what I was missing. Is a Plane an infinitely large construct? And not representative of a triangle?

Comment: yes, a plane goes on for infinity. Any normalized vector can be a direction. If you want a direction between two known points, it would be `(vec3To - vec3From).Normalize()`